# How to add data in datagridview from two different sql tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I need to show data from two different tables in mysql database in DataGridView? 
When I use date from one table I do it with:

```
 using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM POSAO", sqlConn);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataTable.Columns.Add()

            dgvPoslovi.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvPoslovi.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
```

How can I do with data from two different tables?

Comment: How are you getting your data already? Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: I edited my post. See now.

Comment: You can only attach one DataTable to your DataGridView. You need some way of combining the two Sql tables into one. You can do that through an Sql command or through c#.

Comment: What if the two tables column headers are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UNION clause in your query, for simpicity sake assume you have the following 2 tables with the following column names

**Table** STUDENTS

**columns** ST_ROWID, ST_NAME, ST_PHONE

**Table** TEACHERS

**columns** TC_ROWID, TC_NAME, TC_PHONE

```
SELECT ST_NAME AS FULLNAME, ST_PHONE AS PHONENUMBER FROM STUDENTS  
UNION
SELECT TC_NAME AS FULLNAME, TC_PHONE AS PHONENUMBER FROM TEACHERS
```

the above query will return all teachers and students in the same result. if you need to identify which record is student or teacher you could add a fake field to each select statement like below

```
SELECT ST_NAME AS FULLNAME, ST_PHONE AS PHONENUMBER, 'STUDENT' as PERSON_TYPE FROM STUDENTS  
UNION
SELECT TC_NAME AS FULLNAME, TC_PHONE AS PHONENUMBER, 'TEACHER' as PERSON_TYPE FROM TEACHERS
```

**Note** that in order for the UNION to work both select statements need to have the same column names

hope this helps!